# A palavra "carago" é considerada calão?

Tags: significado, interjeições

Ouvi em duas ocasiões essa palavra sendo usada como uma interjeiçaõ (*Sou do Porto, carago!*), em meio a senhoras e crianças. Nunca ouvi um brasileiro usando-a e não tenho certeza quanto ao seu significado, embora guarde uma semelhança com uma outra palavra considerada baixo calão no Brasil.

Comment: Não parece ruim ([Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/carago)): "Expressão designativa de irritação, impaciência, ironia, repulsa ou surpresa. = CARAMBA".

Comment: Se bieres cá a cima abisa, carago, que levo-te a tomar um fino ao Guindalense!

Answer (score 2):

Não é calão no sentido de "linguagem rude", mas é calão no sentido de "linguagem informal" ou "linguagem de rua".
É calão usado mais no norte de Portugal, em particular mas não exclusivamente no Porto.

É uma versão não-mal-educada ([minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath)) de "[caralho](https://dicionario.priberam.org/caralho)" enquanto interjeição:

> 4. [Calão]  Expressão designativa de admiração, surpresa, espanto, indignação ou contrariedade. = CATANO

(Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, consultado em 29-08-2022)

Eu traduziria "caralho" para "damn" e carago para "dang".
Têm exatamente a mesma relação.
Embora "caralho" seja ofensivo, "carago" é uma palavra rude mas que não é ofensiva.

---

Estas outras palavras têm o mesmo uso/significado que "carago":

- catano
- caramba
- caneco
- canudo

Ou, no Brasil :)

- cacete
- cacilda

## Exemplo de uso

Eis um exemplo de uso, num programa humorista da TV.
A personagem Fanã Gomes ([Fernando Gomes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Mendes_Soares_Gomes)) fala como um portuense estereotipado, e a frase não é de todo ofensiva:

> As contas não andam bem por aqui, carago. Tem de pagar as cotas todas até agora.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dg95XLwWNrE#t=186s

Comment: Muito boa a inclusão dos equivalentes em inglês.

Comment: Bem, eu vou a Portugal ainda esse ano, mas acho melhor não incorporar ao meu vocabulário.  Nunca se sabe onde estarão os ouvidos sensíveis.

Comment: Exatamente, usamos "cacete" e "cacilda" como interjeições mais leves.

Comment: Podes usar um dos outros, se te apetecer ser leve e informal. Mas, graças às telenovelas antigas, os portugueses em geral estão perfeitamente habituados ao português brasileiro. Estás perfeitamente seguro que te vão entender, mesmo usando expressões transatlânticas.